# Replace file using std::filesystem

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

Often there is a pattern

1. of writing an output to temporary file(bla.txt.tmp)
2. deleting the original (rm bla.txt)
3. renaming a new one(bla.txt.tmp -> bla.txt)

Is there any utility function in std::filesystem to do this or I need to do steps one by one using rename and remove.

Comment: Why can't you just open the file and directly replace it's contents?

Comment: @NathanOliver OP's pattern is actually very common as a way to avoid incomplete writes caused by system failure or program error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is no such utility function in the standard library. Each step can be done with `std::filesystem` though and you can write such utility function yourself.

`std::filesystem::rename` does perform both steps 2. and 3. in one call, but creating the new file must be done separately.